# How do I identify a string using a wildcard using R?

Tags: r, string, wildcard

I'd like to count the duration of some words containing the number "0" after a string, as shown in the picture (I inserted a red dot under the words with the character I'd like to work with).
Is there anything like a wildcard so that I can work only with the words containing this string?

[Picture]

Comment: Matt, welcome to SO! It is very helpful if you post *usable* data instead of just an image of it. This doesn't mean you cannot include an image (for demonstrative purposes, as you've done), but it makes it a bit easier for us when a representative sample is something we just highlight, copy, paste, and play with. Second, your description is unclear; *"0" after a string* is fine but what string? Third, what have you tried? This might be a perfect fit for regular expressions, but it would help if you show your level of effort. (This isn't a write-my-code service.) Thanks!

Comment: Some references for how to make a great reproducible question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

If the `filename` should not be part of the match, one can utilize the `filename` column to avoid regex from matching:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(no_filename = map2_chr(filename, text, ~gsub(.x, '', .y))) %>%
  filter(grepl("^0", no_filename)) %>%
  select(-no_filename)
```

**Result:**

```
  filename      text     value
1       S2  S20XXXXX 0.2065314
2       S3  S30XXXXX 0.8146400
3       S4  S40XXXXX 0.8123895
4       S6  S60XXXXX 0.1111354
5       S7  S70XXXXX 0.1028646
6       S9  S90XXXXX 0.1306957
7       S9  S90XXXXX 0.3203732
8      S10 S100XXXXX 0.1876911
```

**Note:**

Notice that `S100XXXXX` is matched, but not `S101XXXXX`

**Data:**

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(filename = rep(paste0('S', 1:10), each = 5))
set.seed(123)
df = df %>%
  mutate(text = paste0(filename, sample(c(0:5), 50, replace = TRUE), 
                     paste(rep('X', 5), collapse = "")),
         value = runif(50))
```

Comment: Good solution - does exactly what appears to be requested. The only issue would OP's data- which may me more nuanced that the simulated data used here - voted up!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
grep('0',resultado2$TextGridLabel)
```

to find the rows with a 0. If you want to see the whole dataset subsetted by your search parameter, just use brackets:

```
resultado2[grep('0',resultado2$TextGridLabel),]
```

Comment: This wouldn't work correctly if there is an `S10XXXXXXX` in `TextGridLabel`

Answer (score 0):

You should read the help returned by ?regex.  It will give you a summary of using regular expressions in R.  It will also refer you to a variety of functions that you can use the regex with.

For example, if your data above was in a dataframe, df:

```
grep(x=df$TextGridLabel, pattern="^.*0.+$")
```

would return an index of all the values starting with anything, containing a 0 and having at least one character after the 0.

Cheers!

Comment: This wouldn't work correctly if there is an `S10XXXXXXX` in `TextGridLabel`

Comment: @useR I'm not an expert at using regex... but I can't reproduce your claim.  Here's what I get when I try to see what happens:

`> a <-c("S10XXXXXXXX","D10W","D111America")`
`> grep(a,pattern="^.*0.+$")`
`[1] 1 2`... This is what i would expect and I believe what was asked for.

Comment: I guess since OP's question is not entirely clear, there are different interpretations of what he really wanted. I would think that `"S10XXXXXXXX"` shouldn't be matched since there is no `0` after `S10`, where `S10` is a filename. If `S10` is _not_ the string that OP is referring to in "_the number "0" after a string_", then I agree your solution works as intended, but we won't know for sure until OP clarifies.

Comment: @useR Ah, yes, you are correct of course.  This can all get very hairy if the strings don't have a structure conducive to identifying substrings or at least a clearer question/set of requirements as you point out.  Matt Addison - If useR's interpretation is correct, we'd have to know if the beginning substring always starts S\d{3} or if it can vary and how to correctly identify it before we could exclude 0s in the beginning substring.

Answer (score 0):

The code below does work and it is basically what I need.

```
resultado2[grep('0',resultado2$TextGridLabel),]
```

However, I would like to avoid data such as `S10XXXXXXX` in `TextGridLabel`. I have just edited the original post so that the new picture illustrates better what I'd like to consider.